# Android Studio: Cannot call .remove() on TreeMap while using API level 23 (requires 24)

Tags: android-studio, treemap

I'm using a TreeMap on API level 23 and I would like to remove an element from it but I'm getting an error.

"Call requires API level 24 (current min is 23): java.util.Map#remove"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, before API 24 you cannot remove directly a key from a Map (or something based on Map, like a TreeMap), because it wasn't implemented.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html

But for versions prior API 24 you can do it indirectly, using an Iterator like any other Collection:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {
      {
        put("1stkey", "1stvalue");
        put("2ndkey", "2ndvalue");
      }
    };
for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
      Map.Entry<String, String> entry = it.next();
      if(entry.getKey().equals("2ndkey")) {
        it.remove();
      }
    }
```

**Better:**
You can use both methods choosing with a simple data structure if `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK`is >= 24 or not.